# GDB command aborted for all commands

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, bazel

I am trying to debug a binary on Windows 10 that was built with bazel 5.0. I can get it to run with a debugger on Linux just fine. However, on Windows every single command says `Command Aborted` no matter what I do. I am building with `--compilation_mode=dbg` which should make this work. It even says that it is reading in the symbols from the binary. Is there any way to debug this?

```
Starting program: C:\Users\katso\Documents\GitHub\product\bazel-bin\src\daemon.exe main.cpp
[New Thread 8584.0x1e34]
warning: FTH: (8584): *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***
[New Thread 8584.0x50d8]
[New Thread 8584.0x2078]
[New Thread 8584.0x41e4]
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 4.
Cannot access memory at address 0x14001bf71
Cannot insert breakpoint 4.
Cannot access memory at address 0x140195a80
Cannot insert breakpoint 3.
Cannot access memory at address 0x1404f6fbd
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x14092e7a0
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x1409850b3
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x140985133
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x140e0c801
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x140e0cb61
Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
Cannot access memory at address 0x140f36af0
Cannot insert breakpoint 3.
Cannot access memory at address 0x140f371b0

Command aborted.
```

Comment: Well, you've pretty much answered your own question. gdb was developed on Linux, and is a native Linux application. I haven't checked its documentation, and it might, itself, compile on Windows and offer to debug code on MS-Windows. But only Microsoft really knows how their operating system works, and how to efficiently, and correctly, debug Windows processes. It wouldn't surprise me to learn that gdb on Windows is buggy, capricious, or plain doesn't work well in all or some circumstances.

Comment: Ah well then that would answer my own question! I guess I'll need to figure out a different way to debug this program then. Thank you!

Comment: which version of gdb?

Comment: 8.2.1 is the version.

Comment: I think your executable has ASLR enabled. gdb for Windows can only handle this correctly since version 10, so you need to update.

Comment: Got it. I will update it and then try again.

Comment: Okay I've been trying to update gdb and I couldn't get it building from source unfortunately. I managed to update it within msys but for some reason it says 11.2 is installed but when I type --version I get 9.2 (which is the version within msys). So Ill keep trying but yeah.

Comment: IT WORKED! BLESS YOU.